# How to create an IUPAC dna object without Bio.Alphabet module in Biopython after the update?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am new to bioinformatics, so this question can be a little bit silly, but I really need clear answer and I cant find it anywhere on a web.
I know that before update it was something like that:

```
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
dna_iupac = Seq('ATGATCTCGTAA', IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. What update are you talking about? Why is your question how to do something without Bio.Alphabet but your example shows how to do it with Bio.Alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

Alphabets were removed from Biopython 1.78 because they are very rarely needed and lead to unnecessary complications. You can easily create a sequence object without one, e.g. `Seq('ATG')`. If you really want to record you're using DNA/RNA/Protein you'll have to create an attribute or use the variable name.

You can read more about the history behind this decision if you're interested:

https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet

https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/2046